# Is there a way to avoid blocking social media sharing links from adblock extensions?

Tags: html, adblock

The social media sharing buttons disappear on my site when one of the adblock plugins like Adblock Plus or Adguard is enabled

```
   <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
   <a class='dropdown-trigger circle-icon-btn tooltipped'data-tooltip="Share URL" href='#' data-target='linkDrop<?php echo $url->id ?>'><i class="material-icons">share</i></a>
        <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
        <ul id='linkDrop<?php echo $url->id ?>' class='dropdown-content'>
            <li class="waves-effect"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo ($url->domain ? $url->domain : $this->config["url"]) ?>/<?php echo $url->alias.$url->custom ?>" class="u_share"><span class='sc-icons'><</span>Facebook</a></li>
            <li class="waves-effect"><a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo ($url->domain ? $url->domain : $this->config["url"]) ?>/<?php echo $url->alias.$url->custom ?>" class="u_share"><span class='sc-icons'></span>Twitter</a></li>
            <li class="waves-effect"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php echo ($url->domain ? $url->domain : $this->config["url"]) ?>/<?php echo $url->alias.$url->custom ?>" class="u_share"><span class='sc-icons'><</span>Linkdin</a></li>
            <li class="waves-effect"><a href="mailto:?&body=<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/<?php echo $url->alias.$url->custom ?>"><span class='sc-icons'></span>Email</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The reason is that these add-ons hide social media sharing links, such as

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=`

Is there a way to hide links to avoid hiding buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Adblock plugins not only block ads, but also social icons, social buttons, and social share buttons. In order to avoid this, all you need is change the class/icon name of the icon that adblock hides, to anything else and you’re good to go.

See details [here](https://medium.com/@leo72445/block-adblock-from-blocking-your-social-icons-efb5e7937a65).